# why c++ is rounding of big numbers to ceil and small numbers to floor

Tags: c++, variables, memory-management, integer, c++17

"x","y" are two long long type variables in c++ to which i have assigned two different numbers.

Variable type is long long but i have assigned decimals to the integer.

so i expected that it will trim the decimal part and display only integer part.

it trimmed off the numbers after the decimal and retured an integer.

[image]

Output :

[image]

i was expecting floor() of x but it returned some integer ending with 6 instead of 5, i mean it returned ceil(x).but in the second case it returned floor(y).

and its only occurring when the integer is too long.

So what might be the possible reason for this ?

I am using minGW c++17 version on visual studio code .. but same is happening with online compiler also.

Comment: See [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: I'd suggest [examining the actual value you get](https://i.imgur.com/Kw2ezSB.png) without integers in the picture.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Each initialization involves two conversions, first from the decimal numeral in the source text to `double`, and then from `double` to `long long`.

Let’s discuss the second declaration first. Because `2.001` is a `double` constant, the decimal source text `2.001` must be converted to `double`. Assuming your C implementation uses IEEE-754 binary64, the result is 2.000999999999999889865875957184471189975738525390625. Then, for the initialization, this `double` value is converted to `long long`. This conversion to an integer type discards the fraction, so the result is 2.

In the first declaration, when `9223372036854775.001` is converted to `double`, the result is 9223372036854776. This is because the two `double` numbers nearest 9223372036854775.001 are 9223372036854774 and 9223372036854776. The latter one is closer, so it is chosen. Then this `double` value is converted to `long long`. There is no fraction part, so the result is simply 9223372036854776.

Thus, the first conversion rounds up because it is not simply converting to the nearest `long long` value. It first has to round to the nearest `double` value. And, at the scale of that number, the `double` format does not have enough resolution to represent every integer. It is representing only every second integer: 9223372036854770, …772, …774, …776, …778, and so on. So 9223372036854775 is not a candidate.

Comment: @Hack06: A 64-bit floating-point format can represent at most 2^64 numbers (fewer actually, because some bit patterns are reserved for special meanings). There are infinitely many integers. Therefore, 64 bits is incapable of representing every integer.

Comment: then let them represent whatever they can in a sequential order, not just wtf they want...

Comment: @Hack06: More specifically, a floating-point format consists of a sign, a number of a fixed width in some base (often 2), and an exponent, and the value represent is the number multiplied by the base raised to the power of the exponent. When the exponent is sufficiently large, its multiplication of the fixed-width number means the low digits of that number are scaled beyond the value of 1, so they cannot be incremented by single-integer increments.

Comment: @Hack06: An example of a floating-point format is a sign, three decimal digits, and an exponent. When the exponent is −4 (note: where the starting point of the exponent is is arbitrary ), this format represents numbers from .0100 to .0999. When it is −3, it represents numbers from .100 to .999. When it is −2, it represents numbers from 1.00 to 9.99. When it is −1, it represents numbers from 10.0 to 99.9. When it is 0, it represents numbers from 100 to 999. When it is 1, it represents numbers from 1000 to 9990. At that point, it cannot represent every integer, because the scale is too big.

Comment: @Hack06: A `float` and a `double` uses scientific notation.  It's stored as 1.0240000486373901 * 2^53.  The first part can only have 23 bits, so it can't hold every integer precisely in sequential order.  The type that _does_ do that is... `long long`.  You can also do what you want with fixed point types, but they hold _much_ smaller ranges than a float type as a result.

Comment: @Hack06: Highly recommended: https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf  It's a classic.

Comment: Thanks for enlightenment! I don't know why I missed this part for so long... I knew that there's always a rounding issue with floating point numbers and for precision we need to operate on integer numbers, but not how floating point numbers are represented in the computer memory actually.

Comment: @Hack06: Working with integers gives you different precision, not always better. Floating-point has better precision with small numbers and worse with large numbers. For example, for 8/5, integer arithmetic gives an answer of 1 instead of 1⅗, which is an error of 37.5%. The IEEE-754 32-bit binary format gives an answer of 1.60000002384185791015625, which has an error of only 0.00000149%, so floating-point is hugely more precise than integer in this case. And, of course, with the slightest overflow, integer arithmetic goes completely haywire, whereas floating-point degrades gracefully.

Comment: By precision I meant exact values, not the granularity. For example while counting money in cents, one should use integers to represent the amounts, instead of floating point values. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: u have mentioned nearest numbers are ...........................74 and ...........................76 , why didnt u mentioned .....................75.

Comment: @CheemakurthiMukesh: 9223372036854775 is not representable in a `double`. A `double` represents numbers as a 53-bit integer (or fixed-point number; these are equivalent aside from the scaling used) multiplied by a power of two. The largest 53-bit integer is 9007199254740991, so numbers around 9223372036854775 must be represented as a 53-bit integer multiplied by two (two to the first power). So they are all even. 9223372036854774 is represented as 4611686018427387•2, and 9223372036854776 is represented as 4611686018427388•2. There is no way to represent 9223372036854775.